# ODAC error TNSNAME.ORA al conectarme en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, visual-studio-2017, oracle-11g, odac

Hola buenas hoy me dispuse a instalar ODAC, el cual me llevo varias horas y cuando logre instalarlo y ejecutarlo en Visual Studio 2017, entonces antes de ingresar las credenciales con ORACLE me aparece el siguiente mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego me aparece la ventana normal donde ingreso las credenciales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno busque la ubicación del TNSNAMES.ORA y lo abri pero no se que cambiarle o dejarlo asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna solución para que funcione?, ya que en SQLDEVELOPER me puedo conectar sin problemas

Comment: Tienes que editar los valores que estan entre corchetes angulares (`<` y `>`): IP o nombre del servidor, puerto (default es 1521) y nombre del servicio; abre la configuración de la conexión en SQLDeveloper y copia los valores.

Comment: @Sal muchas gracias estaba editandolo en otro archivo y no en la dirección que se guardo. :D Saludos.